# How can I output query results from Oracle SQL db in HTML?

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a quick and simple way of displaying query results from a orcale sql db in html format?

I would like to be able to setup a local HTML link which can be accessed by folks on my network which pulls in results from a db and displays them.

To provide more info: I have 8 queries setup that I can run locally inside SQL Developer and get results which I can then share with team members. I would like to be able to automate this process where they can simply open a link and it queries the DB and shows them the results automatically. Team members don't have SQL Developer installed on their machines like I do.

Comment: This is very broad to be answer.

Comment: Your existing html page doesn't have to point at a HTML file it can point at just a text file. Then you can just export a normal text file

Comment: The tools help you. With sqldeveloper you can export in html format and you have also filters for data.

Comment: With SQL Developer's built in reporting functionality, I would have to export the data out in HTML format each time someone needs a report. With SQL Plus I keep getting an error 'ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA' even though I am correctly passing the service name in the syntax

Comment: how about using text based output and just using `<pre> stuff </pre>`

Comment: Not sure what <pre> would entail. Can you please elaborate? Sorry, I'm a bit of a novice.

Comment: Why do you need to export as HTML? Does the data needed to be formatted as a HTML page? again if you want to publish your data 'online' it doesn't nned to be html. You can just point to it with an existing static html page. If the data must be in HTML you can just cast each field to text and surround it with required HTML tags. HTML is just a text file with tags in it

Comment: looking at the link in the answer below, looks like SQLPlus will do it for you with `SQLPLUS -MARKUP HTML`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this via SQLPlus... create a bat file that will run sqlplus and generate static html or if you need dynamic you need simple CGI script... example see here: [sqplus results to html](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a82950/ch4.htm#1007638)

Comment: wow that link looks like it was written in the 70s

Comment: it was asked about quick and simple way, it generates you data and html... if you need some styling you can add it... but here the question going to be "too broad and there're many possible answers"

Comment: I didn't ask about anything.  I was just observing.

Comment: Tried to run SQL Plus but my machine is too locked down by IT. Ended up using SSRS to output the report.